# Add one month to current date

Tags: blackberry

I want to add 1 month to date, but it is adding only 4 weeks.

I tried like this,

```
2012-05-04 + DateTimeUtilities.ONEMONTH  = 2012-05-31
```

The result  i am getting is 2012-05-31

I want to add a full month (30 days or 31, or when month is a leapyear 29 or 28).

Answer (score 3):

Try converting your time to a Calendar object then increment the month field:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new Date(timeInMillis));
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
long newTimeInMillis = cal.getTime().getTime();
```

You may want to check for overflow from December to January and increment the year.

The API documentation confirms that DateTimeUtilities.ONEMONTH is four weeks, so what you got is what you should expect.

Comment: I am expecting when Iuse this function (DateTimeUtilities.ONEMONTH)  for adding, get next month  I have not read api carefully  please sory

Comment: Thank u very much Lucifer sir for improving my language

Comment: @RajivGupta You should accept Richard's answer if it answered your question.

Comment: It is not unreasonable to expect that of DateTimeUtilities.ONEMONTH, unfortunately what is reasonable and what is real in programming are often far appart. A careful reading of the API should always be the first step when something doesn't behave the way you think it should. DateTimeUtilities.ONEMONTH is a constant, but months vary in length so it can't possably do what is reasonable to expect. It probably should have been left out of the API.

Comment: I am accepting Richard's answer for our question  Thanku very much

Comment: I guess you are very new to StackOverflow. You don't accept an answer by just stating it, you have to use your UI access to the site as the person asking the question to mark the answer you think is most correct.